# awk way of handling large numbers

Tags: awk

When I try to put below code in command line options it works, but when I put this split in a function and then I give print in end it does not work.

```
$1 is date $2 time and format is as below, here 549 is in milliseconds.      
2013-05-03 18:23:24, 549
```

```
awk -F "[;& ]" '   
     {st[$13]=$1 " " $2}     
     {en[$13]=$1 " " $2}     
    END {    
    for (i in st) {    
        split(st[i],s,"[- :,]")    
        start=mktime(s[1] " " s[2] " " s[3] " " s[4] " " s[5] " " s[6])   

        split(en[i],e,"[- :,]")   
        end=mktime(e[1] " " e[2] " " e[3] " " e[4] " " e[5] " " e[6])    

        diff=(end*1000+e[7])-(start*1000-s[7])    
        print i,diff }    
    }' test.log
```

Here output is in desired format 1960

Code when split in function

```
function calc (date, time, newtime) {  
st[i] = date " " time  
split(st[i],s,"[- :,]")    
start=mktime(s[1] " " s[2] " " s[3] " " s[4] " " s[5] " " s[6])     
newtime=start*1000+s[7]
return newtime    
}
```

o/p time in this format `1.36501e+12`

How would I get this function to have output in right format?

Comment: `st[i]` in `function calc` is...?

Comment: Post your 2 programs (one with the function and one without) along with sample input, expected output, and the output each program produces so we can see exactly what you're doing. Otherwise you're asking us to help you debug a program that we haven't even seen so we'd just be guessing.

Comment: @JS st[i] = date '' '' time . Same as command line

Comment: @Glenn GNU awk version